# Question about a map of spheres and it's fundamental group.

Tags: general-topology

Let $j:S^1\longrightarrow S^4$ be an embedding.  Can $\pi _1(S^4\setminus j(S^1))$ be trivial?  If it is not trivial, can the fundamental group $\pi _1(S^4\setminus j(S^1))$ be abelian?

This is what I have so far:

Since $0<1<4$, then $j:S^1\longrightarrow S^4$ is homotopic to a constant map.  So, $j$ maps all of $S^1$ to single point of $S^4$.  Hence, $\pi _i(S^4)=0$.  This summarizes the different images $S^1$ can be mapped continuously onto $S^4$.

What I want to say is that since $j$ is homotopic to a constant map, then $j(S^1)$ is a point.  So, wouldn't that make $S^4\setminus j(S^1)$ isomorphic to $S^4$?  So, $\pi _1(S^4\setminus j(S^1)) \cong \pi _1(S^4)=0$.

But I'm not sure if that's correct. And the fact that they ask the question about $\pi _1(S^4\setminus j(S^1))$ being abelian, makes me think that the fundamental group isn't trivial.

Comment: Your argument doesn't make sense, I'm sorry. It would imply the complement of a circle in, say, $S^2$ or $S^3$ has the same homotopy type as the original. That's clearly not true. It is, however, true that the complement of an embedded loop in $S^4$ is simply connected. (Maybe you need to say smooth embedding.)

Comment: So what would $\pi _1(S^4\setminus j(S^1))$ be?

Comment: I just said $S^4 \setminus j(S^1)$ is simply connected, at least if $j$ is smooth. It is probably not safe to say that for a wild embedding. What context is the question being asked in? A differential topology class?

Comment: Yea, let's assume the function is smooth.

Comment: So, then it would have trivial fundamental group?

Comment: @Mark: In the smooth setting think about generic transversality of a smooth disk and a smooth circle in $S^4$. In the topological setting things will be quite different: For every $n>2$, $S^n$ contains a subset $A$ homeomorphic to $S^1$,  such that $\pi_1(S^n -A)$ is nontrivial (even infinitely generated).

Comment: So are you saying we can take $A$ to be $j(S^1)$?  How do we know that $j(S^1)$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$? I guess I really don't know what $j(S^1)$ is. How do we use the fact that $j$ is homotopic to a constant map to figure out what $j(S^1)$ is?

Comment: "Let $j$ be an embedding."

Comment: So $j$ is injective and continuous. What else does that tell us?